# Reporting in django

Tags: python, html, django

I need some advice on what to do. I am developing an app for a course at my university. The userstory I working on at the moment is: "As a user I want to be able to report films that doesn´t exist."

My thought was to have a report-button at my film_detail.html, where clicking this button would trigger the BooleanField in my model, and mark the film as reported. When clicking the report-button I was thinking on just having a pop-up window to confirm the reporting, and I believe I won´t need to create a complete new view for this(?).

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this (cause I´m kinda stuck), or maybe having a better idea?

```
**models.py**

class Film(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title_short = models.CharField(max_length=17, default=None, null=True)
    plot = models.TextField()
    poster = models.ImageField(default="default.png", upload_to="posters")
    release_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    reported = models.BooleanField("Is reported", default=False)

    #class Admin:
    #    list_display = ("is_reported")

    #def is_reported(self):
    #    return self.reported == True
    #is_reported.BooleanField = False
```

```
**HTML**

{% extends "board/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <img class="rounded-circle film-img" src="/media/{{object.poster}}">
  <!-- Mulighet for å ha en "add review"-knapp på siden der hvor filmene vises. -->
  <!-- <a href=" {% url 'film-add' %}" class="waves-effect waves-light green btn"><i class="material-icons right">rate_review</i>add review</a> -->
  <a onclick="myFunction()" class="waves-effect waves-light red darken-4 btn"><i class="material-icons right">report</i>report</a>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      alert("Are you sure you want to report this film?");
    }
    </script>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h2 class="film-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
      <p class="film-plot">{{ object.plot }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely different ways on implementing it. One way is to expose an API with a url like:  `films/report` with PUT method. After getting confirmation from the user, you can easily send an Ajax request.